Debian Server with SO_REUSEADDR on Python
I have written just a simple socket server in Python 3.11.2 on Bookworm
Really simple at the moment.
root@9b6f7:~# python3 w1.py
Socket successfully created
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/root/w1.py", line 7, in <module>
        s.bind(('', port))
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use

While testing and writing the script I keep getting Address already in use error when running the script and reading up about the error on sockets I see I need to add SO_REUSEADDR
I have added s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) to my script but still keep getting the Address already in use error especially if the script crashes
Here is my simple script that produces the error when running. Could someone help where I might have gone wrong.
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

print ("Socket successfully created")
port = 1712
s.bind(('', port))
print ("socket binded to %s" %(port))
# put the socket into listening mode
s.listen(5)
print ("socket is listening")
# a forever loop until we interrupt it or an error occurs
while True:
    # Establish connection with client.
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print ('Got connection from', addr )
    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
    c.send('Thank you for connecting'.encode())
    
    c.close()

Thanks

Why on earth are you developing as root?

If you are still getting Address already in use after 2 minutes between invocations, then perhaps there is something still running on that port. ss -ptn dport = :1712 should tell you what is occupying it.

Gerald, this is a cheap KVM server and the default setup is for root

Bob, I ran your command and there is nothing in use, so I ran my script and Ctrl-Z out and ran the command again (still nothing) then ran my script again which produced the error and then ran the command again and still no ports. See next comment for output...
